# SQL Developer Copy Table with Specific Data

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I have a table with 10000+ records, with headings of ID, PRODUCT, U, C, ELONG... (this goes on with various headings).
This table has in the PRODUCT column, 4 possible entries, CAPL, ZOD, HR and PKL. I want to split this up so that there is a table for 'CAPL' only data, ZOD only data HR only data and PKL only data, within SQL Developer. I have run the following:

```
declare
  l_sql varchar2(32767);
  c_tab_comment varchar2(32767);
  procedure run(p_sql varchar2) as
  begin 
     execute immediate p_sql;

  end; 
begin
run('create table "MP".CAPLAAAA as select * from "MP"."LASTQTTBL" where PRODUCT = "CAPL"');
select comments into c_tab_comment from sys.all_TAB_comments where owner = 'MP' and table_name = 'LASTQTTBL' and comments is not null;
run('comment on table MP.CAPLAAAA is '||''''||REPLACE(c_tab_comment, q'[']', q'['']')||'''');

for tc in (select column_name from sys.all_tab_cols where owner = 'MP' and table_name = 'LASTQTTBL')
    loop
   for c in (select comments from sys.all_col_comments where owner = 'MP' and table_name = 'LASTQTTBL' and column_name=tc.column_name) 
   loop 
   run ('comment on column MP.CAPLAAAA.'||tc.column_name||' is '||''''||REPLACE(c.comments, q'[']', q'['']')||'''');
 end loop;
end loop;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL; 
end;
```

But nothing comes out, even when after running it comes up with 'PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.' On the script output.

Am I going wrong anywhere? I would very much appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it necessary to keep all table comments? The following script creates 4 tables related to the number of products in a TEST table.

```
DROP TABLE TEST;
/

CREATE TABLE TEST(A       VARCHAR2(20),
                  B       VARCHAR2(20),
                  C       VARCHAR2(20),
                  D       VARCHAR2(20),
                  PRODUCT VARCHAR2(20)
                  );
/

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('DATA A', 'DATA B,', 'DATA C', 'DATA D', 'CAPL');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('DATA A', 'DATA B,', 'DATA C', 'DATA D', 'CAPL');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('DATA A', 'DATA B,', 'DATA C', 'DATA D', 'ZOD');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('DATA A', 'DATA B,', 'DATA C', 'DATA D', 'ZOD');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('DATA A', 'DATA B,', 'DATA C', 'DATA D', 'HR');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('DATA A', 'DATA B,', 'DATA C', 'DATA D', 'HR');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('DATA A', 'DATA B,', 'DATA C', 'DATA D', 'PKL');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('DATA A', 'DATA B,', 'DATA C', 'DATA D', 'PKL');
/

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    v_Sql VARCHAR2(100);
    v_CodeResp INTEGER;
    v_MsgResp  VARCHAR2(500);
    v_Name VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
    FOR x IN (SELECT PRODUCT
                        FROM TEST
                    GROUP BY PRODUCT)
    LOOP
        v_Name := x.PRODUCT;
        v_Sql := 'CREATE TABLE ' || v_Name || 'AAAA AS SELECT A, B, C, D, PRODUCT FROM TEST WHERE PRODUCT = ' || ''''||v_Name||''''; 
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(v_Sql);
    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            v_CodeResp := SQLCODE;
            v_MsgResp := v_CodeResp || ' ' || SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 300);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_MsgResp);
END;
```